# When creating a new column, why does it work with a function but not without it?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the Titanic dataset to learn to clean data. What I'm trying to do is to create a new column and add values to it. The dataset contains two columns, `'SibSp'`(Sibling & Spouse) and `'Parch'`(Parent & Children) for the passengers. I created a new column 'Family Size' to keep it all in one place.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'train.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

#This is without a function
data['Family Size'] = data['SibSp'] + data['Parch']
print(data)

#This is with a Function
def create_fam_size(data):
    return data['SibSp'] + data['Parch']
data['Family Size'] = create_fam_size(data)
print(data)
```

So far everything is fine. Now, I want to create another column `'Is Alone'` and populate it with a 1 for Alone and a 0 for Not Alone. I tried creating a function to do it, and it works fine.

```
def create_is_alone_column(data, colname):
    def is_alone(a):
        if a == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    return data[colname].apply(is_alone)
data['Is Alone'] = create_is_alone_column(data, 'Family Size')
print(data)
```

But when I try to do it without a function, I get a ValueError and am stumped as to why.

```
data['Is Alone'] = data['Family Size']
if data['Family Size'] == 0:
    data['Is Alone'].apply(0)
else:
    data['Is Alone'].apply(1)
print(data)
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Desktop/tiny.py", line 119, in <module>
    if data['Family Size'] == 0:
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1439, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know it's something ridiculous I'm overlooking, so if anyone can offer me a glimmer of hope, I'll be eternally grateful.

The dataset can be downloaded from here if you want:
https://www.kaggle.com/hesh97/titanicdataset-traincsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```py
[...] # "Family Size" is calculated

data["Alone"] = 0
data.loc[data["Family Size"] == 0, "Alone"] = 1
```

This creates a mask, based on the condition `data["Family Size"] == 0` and sets all values in column `"Alone"` to `1`, where this condition is `True`.

`apply` however does not work the way you used it, see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Because `DataFrame.apply(func, ...)` takes a `func` as input and is carried out on a column (`axis=0`) or on a row (`axis=1`).

You could do this in one line using `numpy`:

```py
data["Alone"] = np.where(data["Family Size"] == 0, 1, 0)
```

See [where docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which is `(condition, x, y)` as "Where True, yield x, otherwise yield y".

Comment: It' works great! Thank you! I'm having trouble figuring out when to use loc[], apply(), and fillna(). Once I learn this, it will be easier.